# Mockito entitymanager return namedQuery

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

so I guess the title says it all if anyone can make it better to help others just tell me to update the title so my problem with Mockito is that I have a code like

```
List<TimeZone> timeZones = entityManager
            .createNamedQuery("get.Alltimezone", TimeZone.class).getResultList();
```

and I want that to return all the timezones but I get a null pointer exception cause when I create a named query with a mock of course I will get a null when .getResultList is called and I need help to fix that I have tried to do in my test this

```
        Query query = mock(Query.class);
    when(caseSetTimezone.entityManager.createNamedQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(query);

    List<TimeZone> captureTimezone;
    ArgumentCaptor<TimeZone> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(TimeZone.class);
    verify(caseSetTimezone.entityManager , times(1)).persist(argumentCaptor.capture());
    captureTimezone = argumentCaptor.getAllValues();

    assertThat(captureTimezone.get(0).getTimezone()).isEqualTo("Europe/Athens");
```

but that doesn't seem to work either I always get the null pointer exception in createNamedQuery how can I mock correctly entity manager so that when I create the named Query it gives back what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so my problem was I try to return a query and not a TypeQuery so that's how it might help someone

```
TypedQuery query = mock(TypedQuery.class);

    when(caseSetTimezone.entityManager.createNamedQuery("get.Alltimezone" , TimeZone.class)).thenReturn(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a set-up for one-param method. What you need is:

```
Query query = mock(Query.class);
    when(caseSetTimezone.entityManager
      .createNamedQuery(anyString(), any(Class.class)).thenReturn(query);
```

of course entityManager needs to be a mock also.

Comment: of course, entity manager is I just didn't upload it my bad I figure out what was the problem so I will post it as answer thanks for your time helping and reading my boring question